# How can I use the system's clipboard in a winui 3 program

Tags: windows, windows-runtime, winui-3

I have buttons for cut, copy and paste. I literally need them to do the exact same thing as their respective keyboard shortcuts would do.

Is there any function that I can stick into an event handler for these buttons to make this work?

Comment: You can use WinRT's `Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer` namespace (`Clipboard` class, etc.) for that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer

Comment: Or, if you are a Win32 app using XAML islands, you can just use the old-style clipboard APIs. The old APIs are still there, and they still work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me show you a simple example using the `Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard` class:

```xml
<StackPanel
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBox />
    <TextBox />
    <TextBox />
    <Button
        x:Name="CutButton"
        Click="CutButton_Click"
        Content="Cut" />
    <Button
        x:Name="CopyButton"
        Click="CopyButton_Click"
        Content="Copy" />
    <Button
        x:Name="PasteButton"
        Click="PasteButton_Click"
        Content="Paste" />
    <TextBox x:Name="PasteTextBox" />
</StackPanel>
```

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    FocusManager.GotFocus += FocusManager_GotFocus;
}

private void FocusManager_GotFocus(object? sender, FocusManagerGotFocusEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewFocusedElement is TextBox textBox)
    {
        _previousFocusedTextBox = textBox;
    }
}
private void CutButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataPackage dataPackage = new();
    dataPackage.RequestedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Move;
    dataPackage.SetText(_previousFocusedTextBox.Text);
    Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
    _previousFocusedTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
}

private void CopyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataPackage dataPackage = new();
    dataPackage.RequestedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy;
    dataPackage.SetText(_previousFocusedTextBox.Text);
    Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
}

private async void PasteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataPackageView dataPackageView = Clipboard.GetContent();

    if (dataPackageView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text) is true)
    {
        this.PasteTextBox.Text = await dataPackageView.GetTextAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: And if I have an app that has a bunch of text and number boxes, do I have to keep track of which one is in focus? Or is the 'SourceTextBox' in your code pulling from somewhere?

Comment: You can use the `FocusManager` to do that. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Did you solve your issue?